# How to get the first file from multiple folders in a document library in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a document library built in SharePoint. Inside this library there are multiple **Document Set** folders that contain template documents. I want to create a view where it only shows the most recent document from each of those folders. The reasoning is to have a library maintainer be able to drop a new file inside of it's designated folder and the users will be able to see a view with the list of the most recent documents from each folder without needing to click into the library and check each folder to see if a new file was uploaded.

Creating a view on SharePoint directly on the website does not satisfy this requirement for displaying the documents as outlined above. I have looked into a **Content Query Web Part**, but this feature also does not have enough settings to make this feature work. I opted to using SharePoint Designer 2013 and created a Custom Web Part and got stuck trying to edit the view. Through SharePoint Designer, I've managed to **sort** the records by their Modification date which puts the most up to date document at the top of the list. Then I managed to **group** the records by the folder name or "type of template". Now I am stuck trying to parse through the XSLT generated source code by SharePoint Designer and figuring out a way how to only display the first record of each folder/group. I currently have a REST call approach using jQuery and it seems to work fine, but I am trying to find if there is an XSLT approach that can solve this problem.

## Update - Adding XML snippet

Here is a snippet of the XML that resembles the library.

```
<Library>
  <Template>
    <FileName>ExpensesReport.xslx</FileName>
    <ModifiedDate>2022-12-10</ModifiedDate>
    <TemplateType>Excel</TemplateType>
  </Template>
  <Template>
    <FileName>Presentation.ppt</FileName>
    <ModifiedDate>2022-12-11</ModifiedDate>
    <TemplateType>PowerPoint</TemplateType>
  </Template>
</Library>
```

Comment: If you can provide a sample XML, it would help us help you

Comment: I have went ahead and added an XML snippet for this question. Thank you for letting me know. @WilliamWalseth

Comment: OK, getting clearer, what's your expected output with this XML?  What XSL have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the solution at the end. I found this resource, [get first item from each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658524/get-xsl-1-0-to-only-show-first-item-in-a-group-within-a-list). I used one of the solutions provided and incorporated it to my problem.

```
test="not(templateType = preceding::Row/@templateType)"
```

Using SharePoint Designer, I used the **filter icon** to add this condition: @fileType != 'not null'. I also added the formula into this section:

```
<xsl:with-param name="Rows" select=$Rows[not(templateType = preceding::Row/@templateType)]
```

With these changes, the view only displays the first file from each template folder.

Comment: I strongly recommend using Muenchian grouping instead of the grossly inefficient method you have chosen.